# JSF Project won't start with JSF implementation 2.2.0 but it is ok with 2.1.19

Tags: jsf, mojarra

These are dependencies in my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And when this is like this, everything is fine. However when I change them to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and deploy my project I am getting:

```
Jul 5, 2013 12:00:50 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/ext;C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
Jul 5, 2013 12:00:50 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 3 msec.
[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.216+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.287+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.497+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 6ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.497+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=14;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 36ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.497+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=13;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 13ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.497+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 19ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.500+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.589+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.796+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|CORE10012: Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/D:/MyDev/6june/target/6june/|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:52.800+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (5) startup time : Felix (1,414ms), startup services(794ms), total(2,208ms)|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:53.411+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.3:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.3:8686/jmxrmi|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:53.676+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.184+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Created EjbThreadPoolExecutor with thread-core-pool-size 16 thread-max-pool-size 32 thread-keep-alive-seconds 60 thread-queue-capacity 2147483647 allow-core-thread-timeout false |#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.206+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.283+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.285+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.311+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.312+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.315+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.320+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.479+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.486+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.492+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.517+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.519+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:55.643+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.037+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.347+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence login successful|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.347+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@328b1323].|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.348+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@328b1323] from index [0] |#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.348+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6ebbd7d] from index [1] |#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.492+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ActorDao: [java:global/sakillaa-webapp/ActorDao!com.tugay.sakkillaa.dao.ActorDao, java:global/sakillaa-webapp/ActorDao]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.528+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB GeneralDao: [java:global/sakillaa-webapp/GeneralDao!com.tugay.sakkillaa.dao.GeneralDao, java:global/sakillaa-webapp/GeneralDao]|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:57.570+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.jboss.weld.Version|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WELD-000900 1.1.8 (Final)|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.018+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.PropertyHandlerManager$DefaultPropertyHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.PropertyHandlerManager$DefaultPropertyHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.PropertyHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.037+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$CompositeComponentTagFactory : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$CompositeComponentTagFactory cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagHandlerFactory|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.371+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ResourceHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.374+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceUnitHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.377+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.WebServiceRefHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.379+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedEJBScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedEJBScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.382+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.EJBHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.385+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedResourceScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedResourceScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.387+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedPersistenceContextScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedPersistenceContextScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.388+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.391+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ResourceScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ResourceScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.393+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.WebServiceRefScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.WebServiceRefScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.396+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedPersistenceUnitScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedPersistenceUnitScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.400+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceContextScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceContextScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.405+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.EJBScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.EJBScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.407+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceContextHandler : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.JndiHandler cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.RuntimeAnnotationHandler|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.410+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedWebServiceRefScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.DelegatedWebServiceRefScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:00:58.412+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error while trying to load Bean Class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceUnitScanner : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.faces.application.annotation.PersistenceUnitScanner cannot access its superinterface com.sun.faces.application.annotation.Scanner|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:01:00.018+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:01:00.500+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/C:/Development/sak/sakillaa-webapp/target/sakillaa-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sakkillaa-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_Persistence logout successful|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:01:00.507+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : FLOW
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FLOW
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.<clinit>(FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:235)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:209)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:149)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:02:11.096+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Server shutdown initiated|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:02:11.122+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR7094: __cp_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:02:13.510+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX002: JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:02:13.511+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX001: JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.|#]

[#|2013-07-05T00:02:13.512+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Shutdown procedure finished|#]
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: According to what written in [this link](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html): The recommend way to use JSF with Maven is to develop on a Java EE certified container and declare a <provided> scope dependency on the appropriate version of the JavaEE API jar. This suggests to run JSF 2.2 in a Java EE 7 container.

Comment: Dunno about Glashfish, but all JEE containers ship with a specific version of JSF. They typically use that to load your project unless told otherwise. How you do this (or if that's even possible), depends on the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Koray,

you've kind of answered your own question here, as you show there is an error when you deploy which is to do with " Flow " class not being available in Glassfish libraries. 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FLOW
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.(FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.java:90).

Your not doing anything wrong there is just a version mismatch between your web app and glassfish. You show that by increasing the api version of your jsf from 2.1.19 to 2.2.0 , your deployment breaks.
 I don't have glassfish but if you look in its libraries you'll find that the com.sun.faces.flow.Flow is not present in the Glassfish version of this jsf-api library.

Do you need to us 2.2.0 of this library , if so you can try adding a provided scope (`<scope>provided</scope>`) to the dependencies and see if glassfish will just use its own. I'm not sure this will work it depends on the class loaders of Glassfish.